# Alamofire + Combine: Get the HTTP response status code

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, combine

I am currently using Alamofire which contains Combine support and using it following way:

```swift
    let request = AF.request(endpoint)

    ...
    request
            .publishDecodable(type: T.self, decoder: decoder)
            .value()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

This will publish result and `AFError` but from subscriber's `.sink`, I can't find anywhere to get the HTTP status code. What's the best way to get the status code in subscriber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the response code, don't erase the `DataPublisher` using `.value()`. Instead, use the `DataResponse` you get from the various `publish` methods, which includes all of the various response information, including status code. You can then `.map` it into whatever type you need.

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 5.X and Xcode 12.4**
For debugging purposes you can intercept the response right before the Combine publisher (publishDecodable()) and get some of the elements of the URL Response, with :

```
session.request(signedRequest)
    .responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy MVVM way:

```
func fetchChats() -> AnyPublisher<ChatListModel, AFError> {
     let url = URL(string: "Your_URL")!
     AF.request(url, method: .get)
            .validate()
            .publishDecodable(type: ChatListModel.self)
            .value()
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Later in viewModel

```
private var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
// some func
      dataManager.fetchChats()
           .sink {[weak self] completion in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                switch error.responseCode {
                case 401:
                    //do something with code
                default:
                   print(error.responseCode)
                }
                print("All errors:\(error)")
            case .finished:
                break
            }
        } receiveValue: {[weak self] message in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.message = message
        }
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
```